# Setting a Param for a Route in Drawer Navigator with react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation with a DrawerNavigator and one main StackNavigator.  In addition to some other screens, my app has 3 main sections, the content of those sections are DB-driven. I'd like to maintain only one SectionScreen component and then pass a sectionId param each time a user taps a different section in the drawer nav and update the section content accordingly.

I can pass a param just fine if I use navigate. But what I'd like is to add the 3 sections to my main StackNavigation, passing a param each time to differentiate the sections and use this param to pull the necessary content.  This way all the Drawer logic is in place, navigationOptions works as expected, etc.  Something like:

```
const stackRoutes = {
  WelcomePage: { screen: WelcomePage },
  ExplorePage: { screen: ExplorePage },
  RideSection: { screen: SectionPage, params: {'sectionId': 1} },
  WalkSection: { screen: SectionPage, params: {'sectionId': 2} },
  BikeSection: { screen: SectionPage, params: {'sectionId': 3} }
}
```

But... this doesn't seem to work.  Any thoughts on the best way to accomplish this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If I understand correctly you would like to render the exact same screen Component with some predefined identifier, to differentiate on which data to load. But could you explain the benefit of this approach for you over just navigating to the exact same screen with different params / props?

Comment: @dentemm I actually think doing what you’re suggesting would work as well, I’m just not sure how to set the routes up in the DrawerNav. It’s possible that to do what I’m hoping for (and what I think you’re suggesting) i would need a totally custom Drawer? In that case, would I simply be using the same .navigate as I would say from a button on a screen. And if so, can I still rig everything up to know which view is focused, etc? Thx!

Comment: Yes a custom drawer is probably the easiest way to go here. It sound a lot more work than it actually is, but react-navigation makes it really easy to use custom component.